# Is there a way to add more than one link to a question when marked as Duplicate?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-deferred

A question on [How to remove the white border of polygons using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203468/how-to-remove-the-white-border-of-polygons-using-qgis) was asked yesterday, and I voted to close the question as a duplicate to another question that has an answer. However, sometimes there are more than one question that can be linked to the OP as exact duplicate, but  with a better solution. But since we only have to provide one link as a duplicate question to the OP, I added another solution in the comment.

I understand that duplicate means an exact question asked two times (with different phrasing, of course), but sometimes it has more than one possible solution.

Is there a way to add more than one link to an OP when marked/voted as Duplicate? In other words, can the system be expanded to give more than one option when adding a link to a related question.

Comment: I've set this to [meta-tag:status-deferred] because as a feature request it could only be implemented via [meta.se] rather than here at [meta.gis.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know the only time you will ever see more than one duplicate to a question is when it's reviewers have differing opinions as to which is more appropriate. Each reviewer is expected to choose the one question that they think represents the same question having been asked before.

To enable a single reviewer to choose more than one duplicate would need an enhancement request to succeed at the site-wide Meta Stack Exchange rather than here. However, I would not expect such a request to be successful.

If it is difficult to choose which previous question of earlier candidates represents a duplicate I think it is a sure sign that more editing to focus the questions involved in the dilemma or trilemma facing you is needed.

This appears to be the same question that you are asking, asked previously at Meta Stack Exchange: [Allow same user to add multiple links as possible duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1385/215590)

Comment: But sometimes choosing an exact duplicate question, when marking a question as duplicate, is not listed in the drop-down menu . I actually found the duplicate question - the one I posted in the comment in the original OP - from google search. At least if we have an option to edit the link of the duplicate question to the more appropriate one, it will be more helpful and a positive feature.

Comment: I think the response to that from [meta.se] would be that in such a case you should bring it to the per-site Meta and/or flag a Mod to assist re-opening and then re-closing as a new duplicate.

Comment: I flagged the Moderator to re-open the question, so I can update the link?

Comment: Thanks for re-opening the question again, but it seems I cannot update the link to the duplicate question or do anything. Do I have to keep the question as it is? Or do I have to do something else?

Comment: If you have refreshed it, then I would have expected you could use your [vote to close privilege](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions).  It may be that by exercising your close vote on the first duplicate you are blocked from another on this question.  I was hoping to leave the community to decide but as an expedient I'll try and supervote it closed as the duplicate that you suggested.  My quick investigation has me thinking the duplicate you found is the one to go with.  I'm happy for others to re-open if I get it wrong.